# Pizza dough is way too wet, already in the oven. Fix?

Tags: rice, flour, pizza

I'm cooking some pizza with homemade dough, using rice flour. I put all of the toppings on the pizza already, and put it in the oven. It's been there for quite some time, but the dough is just way too moist for it to cook properly. It's just a mushy mess.

I turned the oven off and it's cooling down now. The tomato sauce and cheese on top is almost burnt already.

What are my options to salvage this mess?

Thanks!

Comment: "using rice flour"? Rice "flour" is not flour, it is pure starch. Pizza dough needs lots of gluten. Unless you are using a proper gluten free recipe with lots of thickeners, there is just no way to make pizza dough with rice flour. I guess you could make a kind of hard crust by drying it out substantially first, but it will not taste like pizza.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably out of luck trying to save it as a pizza, but one thing you might try is finishing the cooking on the stovetop. Put in in a big skillet or even on some foil and start with medium heat. It's worth a shot. Good Luck.

Comment: Agreed, most gluten free pizza recipes are mostly rice flour and require significant pre-baking before adding any sauce or toppings.